# What happendd if I change the instance variable of subclass in Base class function

Tags: ruby

I wonder if I write a function of base class and modified the subclass instance variable inside that function, how can ruby distinguish them? For example:

```
class Parent
  def change_name
    @name = 'Parent'
  end
end

class Subclass < Parent
  def initialize 
    @name = "subclass"
  end

  def get_name
    @name
  end
end

sub_class = Subclass.new
sub_class.change_name
sub_class.get_name     #=> Parent
```

What confused me is that `@name` is the instance variable of Subclass, how can the function `change_name` change it just like `@name` was belongs to
Base class. Is it in ruby shared the same public instance variable between Base and Sub class.

Comment: I didn't do ruby for quite some time, but as far as I remember, ruby doesn't initialize the members of a class when the class will be created, but when the member will be used. ie if you create parent, there is no member @name, but as soon as you call the method change_name there will be.

Comment: Are  the `@name` in parent  and `@name`in subclass the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, the parent and subclass class don't have separate objects. When you create an instance of the subclass class, it is also an instance of the parent class. There is one object and it is both classes at once.

Since there is only one object, there is only one set of instance variables. So in effect, you can think of this like the following:

```
class CombinedClass
 def initialize 
    @name = "subclass"
  end

  def get_name
    @name
  end

  def change_name
    @name = 'Parent'
  end
end

combined_class = CombinedClass.new
combined_class.change_name
combined_class.get_name     #=> Parent
```

Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Yes , the example makes sense。Thanks！I get the concept from C++ ,but it seems different from C++ in ruby.